# How could a sapient species lose its intelligence?

Tags: science-based, biology, evolution, sapience

A relatively common idea in Sci-Fi and especially speculative evolution is the idea of humans or some other intelligent species ending up losing their sapience(often done for the sake of horror).

While the most common explanation(forced genetic modification) makes sense, I've always been skeptical of the idea of it happening naturally giving how much of an edge it's given us, especially in regards to the idea of it being from some massive cataclysm.

So what are some potential explanations for why a sapient species would end up losing its intelligence?

Comment: "*giving how much of an edge its given us*" Toss you in the middle of humanity's native environment of the African wilderness and see how well you do. If you do the same with most other creatures they will survive just fine. It's a form of survivorship bias.

Comment: *Idiocracy* and *The Marching Morons* give some clues.

Comment: A whole species ... seems unlikely, on less than an evolutionary timescale. All individuals of that species ... consider the fate of octopodes here on earth. To breed is to die. To become a fairly mindless child-protector would be equally possible.

Comment: Kit kot will do it.

Comment: Are we talking about the evolution of a species or a single individual? It is easy to damage an individual's brain.

Comment: Cable "news"..?

Comment: Kurt Vonnegut did a such a story in "Galapagos"  " all the sorrows of humankind were caused by "the only true villain in my story: the oversized human brain". Natural selection eliminates this problem, since the humans best fitted to Santa Rosalia were those who could swim best, which required a streamlined head, which in turn required a smaller brain." (Wikipedia)

Comment: For scale, it's estimated that Kasparov burned about 3000 Calories/day playing chess.  He apparently had to drop out of a few tournaments because he wasn't able to keep his weight up.  So that's 1000 Calories/day over the average man's base rate, just from brain usage.

Comment: Are you looking for an evolutionary answer or an immediate answer?

Comment: @Xavon_Wrentaile evolutionary answer

Comment: https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/cat-brains-have-shrunk-with-domestication-180979516/

Comment: @RonJohn Ah yes, Idiocracy, the *documentary*.

Comment: @Michael What you're saying is that you want us to put water on the crops. *Water*, like out the *toilet*?

Comment: @Perkins Yes, Champion chess players burn a lot of extra calories while playing, but not because they are thinking too hard.  Competition (be it physical or mental) triggers an adrenaline response which results in increased heart-rate, breathing, muscle tension, etc.   Intense, non-stop thinking can only increase calorie usage by up to about 25 calories per hour; so, Kasparov was only burning 100-200 extra calories per day thinking, and another 800-900 calories a day from stress.

Comment: @DKNguyen Not really. Humans became the dominant species on the planet because of our intelligence even before we figured out fire. Even in Africa. And a group of people (since we are not a solitude animal your point about tossing someone alone is kinda pointless) should survive african wilderness - better than majority of other creatures.

Comment: @Perkins The 2000 calorie figure is not based on average needs. It's more or less a round arbitrary number that they started putting on the Nutrition Label. They need some figure to calculate the percentages, and a consistent and easily understandable and memorable one is preferable. The label notes this with an asterisk (`*Percent daily values based on a 2000 calorie diet`). Average healthful needs are more like 2800 calories per day.

Comment: The invention of television ought to do it.

Comment: @DKNguyen with one human sure, toss a few dozen humans together anywhere and we out preform almost anything. Humans with sharp sticks and fire hunted half the megafauna on the planet to extinction.

Comment: @Negdo no we did not , fire predates homo sapiens by a large margin, humans have always had fire. It is likely what allowed us to evolve such large brains in the first place.

Comment: @fredsbend  There are a lot of variables in that for age, weight, sex, and activity level.  The 2000 was the original estimate for a man working a desk job and not really doing much for exercise.  Turns out that's terrible for your health in the long-run.  Meanwhile, people who do a lot of strenuous physical activity may need over three times that amount.

Answer (score 31):

### Losing Our Natural Intelligence: Idiocracy

The movie Idiocracy so famously answered this question, that the movie's Title has become a bit of a trope.  Idiocracy predicts 3 evolutionary pressures that work in tandem to reduce intelligence in an advanced society.

#### 1. Technology replaces the need for intelligence.

As technology becomes more advanced and automated, the intelligence required to survive is no longer important.  Being smart enough to find ways to irrigate your fields with water gives you a much better chance of survival in a neolithic society than the guy who does not. But, in the modern world, you can be pretty much anywhere between mentally disabled and a genius and still only have a negligible chance of actually starving to death.  So stupidity is not selected against like it used to be.

["One of the most consistently replicated findings in the social sciences has been the negative relationship of socioeconomic status (SES) with mental illness"](https://www.apa.org/pubs/journals/releases/ort-7513.pdf). This means that in places where socioeconomic status impacts your odds of survival, that it can be used as a good predictor of if you are likely to pass on psychological deficiencies.

So, in countries with less access to technology, where starvation is still a major source of natural selection, being mentally deficient increases ones odds of starving to death by a greater margin than places that have the technology and resources to care for thier poor.  For example, when you compare the food security rate of [Iran](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6983490/) with the [United States](https://www.apa.org/news/press/releases/2005/03/low-ses), you see that the effect of being poor increases your odds of going hungry by very similar ratios, but in the United States, the food insecurity rate is only 12.5% whereas in Iran, it is 37.8%.  This means that your socio-economic status is about 3 times as likely to cause you to starve in Iran as in the United States.

So even if people with mental disabilities in poorer countries are being born at the same rate as mentally healthy people, they die off more quickly removing them from the gene pool encouraging the evolution of greater intelligence.  This factor alone does not encourage people to evolve to be dumber, but it does take away the evolutionary presure that causes us to evolve to be smarter.

#### 2. The intelligent are often targeted in politics.

[Anti-intellectualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-intellectualism) is a common part of modern politics for a number of reasons.  People in power often target the intelligent middle class because smart, well educated people are much harder to control, so they  use the media to push ideas that smart people are dangerous or otherwise socially contemptable.  Different kinds of 20th century governments attacked thier own intellectuals in different ways.  In Communist Russia, the "Great Purge" included the slaughter of writers, artists, and anyone else perceived as having the mental faculties to be a threat to social equality.  In the Fascist states of Central Europe, philosophies arose that condemned any knowledge that was not "practical" making it easy for leaders to suppress any line of thinking that moved against the state, and the people doing that thinking along with it.  Then you have the Populist movements more common in the far Western nations that emphasized a uniformity among all people which lead to the out-casting of the overly smart.

While anti-intellectualism does not in every case lead to the intelligent members of society being killed, it does make them less sexually fit.  Up until very recently, being labeled a "Nerd" was a good way to loose a lot of your reproductive rights; so, smart people had far fewer children.  While many of the Anti-intellectualism trends of the 20th century have been reversed in Western Civilization, in many parts of Asia, being too smart is still a good way to have society turn against you.  If these trends ebb and flow over enough generations, you will see a strong selection towards lesser intelligence.

#### 3. Intelligence itself selects against reproduction.

In the past, smart people had a lot of children because it was the duty of a child to support thier parents in old age.  You did not plan for retirement by investing in 401ks and Social Security, you planned for retirement by having as many children as you could afford to support when you were young so that when you get too old to support yourself, they would do it for you.  However, now that there is no longer a practical benefit to have kids, smart people are choosing to have fewer children than they did before.  It used to be common for people of lower socio-economic status to have 3-5 children and people of higher status to have 6-9 children, but now that there is no security in having children, we've seen the lower echelons of society continue to average about 3-5 children, but in many particularly educated parts of the world, the wealthy are averaging less than 2.  This means that the drop off in reproductive rates among socialized nations is not uniform, but that it is specifically causing a drop off in the reproductive rates of its smarter members.

Since smart people are generally not meeting a the basic rate of replacement, then even if they are intelligent enough to survive to reproductive age 100% of the time, their population is dwindling and being replaced by people with people less intelligent than themselves.

### Losing Our Nurtured Intelligence: Dark Age Collapse

Intelligence can best be described as a combination of Nature and Nurture.  For example, [IQ tests performed on in the Sub-Saharan region](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0160289609001275) where there is minimal access to education and technology show an average IQ of 68-71.  By civilized standards this makes the average Sub-Saharan person qualify as legally retarded.  Thier brains are not smaller, they are just as genetically capable of intelligence as civilized humans, they simply fail to develop that intelligence due to lack of exposure.  Even though they are just as good at solving the problems that they face on a daily basis as we are, they face much fewer complex problems that require logic, math, literacy, and/or science to overcome.

> I've always been skeptical of the idea of it happening naturally giving how much of an edge it's given us, especially in regards to the idea of it being from some massive cataclysm.

Going from a state of High civilization to Low civilization has certainly happened several times in human history as the result of massive cataclysms, and has had profound, measurable impacts on how innovative the peoples of those regions were.  The [Bronze Age collapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_Bronze_Age_collapse) for example was a time period between 1200-1150BC where a series of wars and famines destroyed most major cities in the Eastern Mediterranean region causing population declines in some areas as high as 90%.  The sophistication of art, writing, and technology that was common of the late bronze age largely disappeared from this region for 100s of years as these regions reverted to a more-or-less stone-age civilizations before new technology, socio-economic structures, and classical philosophy took root.  Something similar happened after the fall of Rome too.  Rome brought a level of technology similar to the Early Industrial Revolution to most of Europe.  They had indoor plumbing, water powered factories, complex logistics networks, a formal school system, etc. but after [Rome was destroyed in the Goth War of 535-562AD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gothic_War_(535%E2%80%93554)) ([No not 476AD](https://time.com/6101964/fabricated-fall-rome-lessons-history/)) most of that disappeared and triggered the Early Medieval Dark Age.

These cataclysms cause a lose in general intelligence because they destroyed the underlying framework that educates, encourages, and enables the development of intelligence. But, the effects of a cataclysms is only temporary.  Within a few hundred years, people tend to rebuild those missing frameworks, and it is usually followed by an intellectual golden age like the Greek Classical Era or the European Renaissance.

Comment: As sad as it is, this is actually a very good answer. And not only is it good, it is pretty much proving itself more and more daily. Look at everything from our politics, entitlement programs, and average education level of the generations replacing us because the world demands no better anymore. The rise of torrents of information sources, most, largely inaccurate, at a the touch of an apathetic finger... https://map.barbarabush.org/overview/#intro  so it is not as much "how can it happen?" as much as a model for "how is it happening?"

Comment: Surprised I had to scroll down this far to find this answer.

Comment: Obligatory xkcd https://xkcd.com/603/ - nice theory except everything it says is wrong, false, the opposite of true.

Comment: That was the worst XKCD I've ever seen. Just an ad hominem rant that didn't even attempt to confront the  fact that the more education people have, the less children they have, and the recent reversal of the Flynn Effect.

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant Yes, Randall Munroe is a respectably smart guy, but missed the fact that Ideocracy is not a social problem, it is a genetic one.  Our methods and saturation of education are still getting better which continues to have a positive outcome, but the reproductive trends suggest that the average brain is about to get a whole lot worse.  It's like if software design kept getting better, but we started making worse computer hardware, it would take a while to notice the hardware decline.

Comment: @Nosajimiki I'm genuinely curious, what reproductive trends? If it is just the increase in mental illness diagnoses, then that is almost certainly correlation caused by improved diagnostic practices and social acceptance. Just a few decades ago, not talking about the "retarded" kid was the social norm.

Comment: @Nosajimiki In which country? In Angolophone countries, one has only to look at school curricula and exams to belie that. I'm not American but you can see what US kids are expected to have learned at ages 6,7,8,etc,  and sorry, they must be *morons*. My own country has more or less gone from the top of the OECD to near the bottom in literacy and maths, so they aren't getting better here. As far as I can tell, not a single pedagogical development pushed by academia in 20 years has been based on evidence. Child centreing, abandoning phonics, eliminating rote learning, etc.

Comment: There seems to be adequate evidence for decline in both our genetic stock and schooling.

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant Child centering, abandoning phonics, eliminating rote learning, etc. are side effects of research based methods of improving learning that address our new understanding of developmental psychology.  It looks like stupification to those of us who learned differently, but "child centering" prevents learning resistance; so, it may slows down early education a, bit  but it vastly improves learning over the course of a student's entire academic career. Traditional phonics was replaced with things like the dibbles method which teaches general literacy faster.

Comment: Common core math takes more time to teach, but it allows a wider range of students to achieve a proficiency in math. Rote learning is practically useless in a modern context, in the age of the internet, if you can learn 10 concepts in the same time that someone else learns 10 facts about a single concept, you've learned how to solve 10 times as many problems, because knowing the concepts is enough to look up the facts.

Comment: All these things can mask a decrease in stock because a child who stays motivated will spend a lot more effort over his carrier learning, new phonics reduces the amount you need to memorize to learn to read, people with various handicaps that would have prevented them from learning math, can now get it, and even if you can only learn 3 concepts, you can still solve more problems than the guy who rote memorized 10 facts on 1 concept.

Comment: @Nosajimiki I'll bite. There's never been a single large number study that actually shows they work. They're all based on either pure theory/ideology, or on very small number, uncontrolled studies. Against them, you have hard data (in the case of phonics), reasonable theoretical objections (how does a teacher manage a lesson with 20 to 30 different centres), and the 'natural' experiment that is the increasing gap between East Asian countries that say no to all that BS, and the West (as well as a few Western counterexamples like Katharine Birbalsingh and co). My country has a very high number

Comment: of East Asian high school students that move over here, and the gap in skill and knowledge between them and  ours is staggering. It's 2 - 3 years equivalent by the end of high school; their average 17 year olds can blitz our first year uni courses with A's. But this detracts from my main challenge: find a single controlled large number study that justifies any of those things on the basis of actual results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146629/discussion-between-ancientgiantpottedplant-and-nosajimiki).

Comment: I don't think "anti intellectualism" is a much about intelligence as you claim. It's more about believing in and belonging to a system of elitism. A lot of people at the top believe they earned though their cunning every step that led there, but that's clearly not true for anybody. Time and place matter more, and no one has earned those. "Common folk" have expressed this sentiment since the beginning, and literature shows this, while arrogant kings and emperors toot their own horns.

Comment: @fredsbend  Anti-intellectualism is not what happens when commoners think leadership is dumber than them.  It's what happens when leaders fear that commoners are smart enough to be a threat, and they push back by eliminating people who may be smart enough to replace them.  You are right that it stems from elitism, but the outcome is the removal of intelligence from your society which was my point.

Comment: @Nosajimiki I guess my point then is that you are mistaken. Leadership eliminating competitors is commonplace, and such competitors being intelligent or not doesn't really seem relevant to the leaders. "Burning heretics" and the like is about putting a stymie on influential people. Intelligence is irrelevant. Even the message is irrelevant. It's who is saying it that matters.

Comment: @fredsbend Anti-Intellectualism is not the same as a political cleansing.  It's not about taking out individual competitors or ideas, but about taking out entire classes of people from which competition is likely to arise.  So they go after well educated groups like professors, lawyers, psychologists, scientists, engineers, etc. and leave alone or prop up any groups that show no particular inclination towards knowledge and understanding.

Comment: @Nosajimiki I'm with you here. CGP Grey has an excellent video essay on "The Rules For Rulers", and a major takeaway is that modern governments are stable in two basic flavors; dictatorships funded by state-owned labor-independent wealth with a destitute populace (no means to revolt, at least not successfully), and advanced economies built on governments designed to resist one-party dominance (low motive to revolt). In between, you have a valley of revolution, where the common people have the means and motive to make their lives better by kicking the king off the hill.

Comment: This valley involves countries where the main source of State funding is an export requiring a relatively skilled/educated workforce, and the income from that export isn't enough to keep everyone happy. Your economic and military/security leaders are expecting a large share of that wealth in return for keeping you in power; fail to meet their expectations and they'll have you replaced. But, stiff the working class and they'll stop working, then stops the flow of money to those kingmakers, and see previous scenario.

Comment: The U.S. is generally counted among the advanced economies with totalitarianism-proof government structure; indeed our Constitution requires our government to function with broad consensus or not at all. However, the gridlock caused by such polarized parties as we now have is being blamed on the system itself; "it would be so much easier if we could just X". Easy to say when you like the party in power. When the White House is occupied by a man you wouldn't put in charge of cleaning up dog crap at the park, the ability to do X can easily come back to haunt you.

Comment: @KeithS Yes, the US government is totalitarian resistant, but I would not describe it as totalitarian proof. It has a winner-takes-all electoral system which can become very unstable when just a little bit out of balance.  The US Civil War was fought over the Northern Republicans gaining majority in the House of Reps, Senate, Presidency, and certain upcoming majority in the Supreme Court effectively leaving the South's interests entirely unrepresented in the Federal Government.

Comment: The 2020 insurrection happened literally the same day that the Democrats won the presidency recreating the same circumstance that triggered the Civil War in 1861.

Comment: the problem with this is there is a very strong evolutionary pressure for mate selection, intelligence makes you better at resource acquisition and thus mating advantage regardless of technology. most selective pressures in within the species for mates.  If anything technology makes the effect stronger since it allows less equality to persist.  the movie is a fun idea but it is bad science. Also a loss of technology is not the same thing as a loss of intelligence, heck intelligence evolved with minimal technology.

Comment: @John Fitness is not dictated by how prosperous you are but by how many offspring you can successfully raise.  Even if an intelligent mate is theoretically more desirable, if they produce less children in a society where technology ensures that nearly all children have an equal chance of reaching maturity, then they are selectively less fit.

Comment: So yes, technology evolved with minimal technology because when you have minimal technology, the dumb die off and the intelligent survive.  But once technology reaches anything close to post-scarcity, the dumb stop dying off and it becomes a question of who CHOOSES to have more children.

Comment: @Nosajimiki incorrect fitness is about how many genes you pass into the population over successive generations, having few children and lots of grandchildren for instance is more successful than the inverse. it is an aspect of r and K selection and explains demographic transition. Also failing to reproduce is not the same as having died, 10 children who can't find mates is much worse that 2 who find mates easily, this is not even a controversial aspect of evolution. Also there is no such thing as a post scarcity society, its just a thought experiment, mates will always be a limiting factor.

Comment: @John Dumb people have no problem finding other dumb people to procreate with.  It's actually easier than smart people finding smart people to procreate with because dumb people have more children; so, you have a bigger dating pool of willing partners.  Also, smart people are both having fewer kids and a higher % of kids that choose not to procreate; so, the grandchild argument does not work.

Comment: Also, I said "anything close to post-scarcity" for a reason.  Not as in a society without scarcity, but a society that has little enough scarcity to keep its less productive members of society reasonably well taken care of.

Comment: @Nosajimiki the grandkid example was me giving an example of how complex evolutionary success is, If you want to dive into the details of how it works I will provide a link..   Also by your logic peacocks should not have large display tails because small tail peacocks can more easily find other peacocks. Sexual selection is not as straightforward as you think. https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspb.2019.2468 You can argue against it all you want but the effect is both observed and mathematically explained in humans.

Comment: @Nosajimiki in such a society sexual selection matters even more, because mate selection are the primary limiting factor. Sorry the movie does not stand up to the science.

Comment: @John, you are over simplifying how sexual selection works.  There have been several psychological studies showing that common people have the easiest time finding sexual partners.  People who are exceptionally smart, rich, or beautiful typically have less sex and fewer sexual partners than common people.  People generally partner up with people of similar "quality" to themselves,  So, if there are fewer smart people born, being smart does not mean you have less competition because you are smart, it means you have fewer options because most people are too dumb for you.

Comment: # sexual partners is not equal to number genes passed into the next generation, Again do you know what K strategy is? We know that on most measurable metrics  intelligence if people is rising, (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0028393208004429?via%3Dihub),  so the data does not follow from your assumptions. Can the rest of us see these studies because as soon as I looked I found the opposite, a preference for intelligence https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1090513808000792 and https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-3-319-59531-3_85-1

Comment: @John Preference is not the same as offspring per generation.  Even if women prefer smarter men, the average smart man is still having fewer children than the average dumb man.  People don't compete for the best, they compete for the best they can get.  They generally don't say, "if I can't have a guy with a 130 IQ, I just won't have sex", unless they have the health/beauty/intelligence factors to realistically achieve that goal, and if they fail to find Mr. 130 for long enough, they drop thier standards until they find what works.

Comment: K strategy only improves your reproductive fitness if a more r strategy is resulting in an increased death+celibacy rate.  But as I demonstrate in section 1, The death rate of r selected people is dropping in developed countries and in section 3 I demonstrated that the celibacy rate of K selected individuals is increasing.  Researchers like the Daniel R. Vining, Jr.,  Retherford, Richard Lynn,  and Sewell all concluded that Americans have been losing 0.55 or more IQ points per generation over the past few decades.

Comment: I have explained this several times, number of offspring is not the only measure of evolutionary fitness, If you learn nothing else from this conversation please learn that, Gene transmition success cannot be measured solely by number of offspring. You have demonstrated nothing, you have claimed several things without backing it up, and when I provided sources showing the opposite of what you claim you simply ignore it. Now you  try Daniel R. Vining, Jr, the bell curve guy, who's work was so flawed and racist no normal journal will touch it.  Please learn biology newer than the 80's. I'm done

Comment: @John Daniel R. Vining's work showed a faster decline in blacks (racist sure), but his data showed that everyone was getting dumber, not just blacks.  If his study was pure racism, and no facts, then his white supremacist ass would have claimed whites were getting smarter.  Also, every attempt there after to discredit his work showed similar IQ decline even though his racial bias was clearly messed up.

Comment: as for genetic fitness, you are simply mistaken.  You are making the common mistake of thinking individual fitness = genetic fitness which is perhaps the most basic and common mistake people have when talking about evolution.  If you have fewer children, and thier they don't have a higher survival\*procreation rate than a competing genetic line, they are genetically less fit. You've yet to cite a single fact that disputes this.  All of your studies are based on mating preference which only matters if matting preference results in a lower survival\*procreation rate for your competition.

Answer (score 20):

**Environmental Pressure**

As other answers have stated, the environment dictates evolution. Take, as an example, H. G. Wells' *The Time Machine*. For millennia, the Eloi have had their needs met without any effort on their part. After a certain point, the "edge" intelligence gives a species that never has to work for survival will likely become vestigial and die off.

Comment: Endless peace, comfort, and welfare.

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant "Endless peace" - it may very much depend on technological level. In modern society, people are frequently drafted into war regardless of intelligence (except arguably for people who lie their way out of the draft, but whether that's a beneficial trait for humanity is highly doubtful), and war happens at far too big of a scale for intelligence to be hugely beneficial to an individual soldier. And across societies, any society that gets the upper hand at one point can keep other societies from advancing through force. It might work for primitive settlements though.

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant "Welfare" - assuming everyone is given equal means and opportunity to succeed, regardless of where they're born (most definitely not the case in modern society). "Comfort" - discomfort doesn't stop people from having children, unless you push them to depression or suicide, but that's... In any case, much of modern "comfort" factors affect people across entire genders, races, etc., that has little to no correlation with intelligence. You'd need to implement these measures in a very specific way, in a very specific society, to negatively affect intelligence selection.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Whoosh, have you read The Time Traveller?

Comment: Evolutionarily speaking, it's more about benefit to the individual than to the species. If people didn't need intelligence for survival, there would still be an evolutionary benefit if being intelligent helped you to outwit rival humans and breed more. (Though it's also possible for more intelligence to lead to fewer children...)

Answer (score 19):

Intelligence is costly: it takes time and resources to build such brain, and the environment has to be above certain standards, otherwise the result can be intelligent but emotionally dysfunctional mind.

The social environment can also impose restrictions: eg. inquisitive and questioning mind -- typically associated with higher intelligence -- can be classified as an unwanted trait. Intelligent creature can be seen as a threat to the status quo. Powers that be might not like to be challenged.

The cons are always weighted against the pros. It does not always pay off to be intelligent. If the cons are too prevalent, viability of the whole population can be enhanced if everyone is less intelligent.

Comment: _"otherwise the result can be intelligent but emotionally dysfunctional mind"_ - Damn, I didn't come here to see people talking about me. ;-(

Comment: @RedBanana Don't worry, emotional dysfunction can be healed, stupidity cannot.

Answer (score 10):

Two environmental factors, perhaps working in tandem:

1. Brains are expensive in themselves, costing energy, taking time to build, etc.  If they are excessive, so that a stupider being lives better and has more children with that energy and time, the being will evolve stupider.
2. Brains may lead beings to do stupid things out of curiosity.  In a hazardous environment, this may be a danger in itself.  A stupid, incurious being will live to have children.

Comment: There was an example of the tides going out in...Sri Lanka I think? I forget where but elephants lived there. When the tides went out people headed to the beach out of curiosity but animals like elephants moved away. The tsunami ended up killing many more people than animals like elephants as a result. It wasn't known why the elephants moved away but it was theorized they were simply moving away from the source of infrasound. However other animals also moved away from the incoming tsunami. Just people did not because they were curious about an unusual event.

Comment: @DKNguyen I had heard a similar story of "ancient wisdom". A native tribe knew it as a warning signal, and so moved inland. So, intelligence for the win, since the dummies drowned.

Comment: brains are expensive but they vastly improve your ability to find calories, from fish weirs, to cooking roots, to building snares.

Comment: @John  Some species increase brain power, some species decrease it.  Clearly evolution can go both ways.

Comment: Sure but not for the reason you give, more intelligent does not equal better at getting food, but human level intelligence does, humans  are way better at finding food than other primates, its hard to beat the beneficial effects of cooking and tools. cooking alone doubles your calorie intake.

Answer (score 8):

Evolution takes orders of magnitude longer to kick in than how far movies are willing to look forward, therefore they need to have a bigger impact events than what evolution may provide. That being said, within hundreds of thousands of years any of the below could happen.

## Constant factors impairing brain

There are multiple factors that could cause the big brains of ours (I use humans as an example but should apply to most carbon-based sapience) to be using up too much energy for the gains they provide:

1. Low oxygen. In a low oxygen environment the brain is one of the first organs to catastrophically fail. The humans surviving lower oxygen % would be the ones who have lower oxygen needs by having lower weight, brain activity etc.
2. Low air pressure. Low air pressure reduces humans' ability to absorb oxygen. This ties back to 1.
3. Constant exposure to psychoactive substances (e.g. alcohol). If the brain is impaired it does not provide that much of an evolutionary advantage.

## Factors impacting birth

Anywhere where a narrower hip is an advantage above brains the hips may get narrower leading to higher birth mortality of the bigger headed infants.

## Factors impacting lifespan

Currently humans take about 12 years to be fertile and they take much of this time to develop mental capabilities (complex language, mathematics, drawing etc.) which is a fair tradeoff for a 50+ year expected lifespan. If external factors (famine, lack of water, pandemics, radiation etc.) were to reduce the expected lifetime drastically then there would be less time to be dedicated to education. This in turn would probably lead to being smart being less of an advantage.

Answer (score 7):

A lot of what you consider "sapience" is really just nurture, not nature. If you look at primitive tribes, they are quite a bit different from what you likely take as a "normal" human, but even they have substantial culture. You should really look at [wild children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feral_child) to see what the "physiological foundation of sapience" looks like.

The basis for development of intelligence, culture and society is steeped in mystery. You can't have a "hard science" answer to it. However, we can speculate that human brain capacity is just barely over the threshold for what's needed to be civilized. Clearly, even a little capacity for culture snowballs quickly and amplifies what faculties the brain has. Therefore, it's unlikely that truly advanced sapience would have evolved in humans. As soon as basic sapience came about, culture would begin to dominate fitness, and the evolutionary pressure on innate sapience would disappear.

If you buy this line, you can conceptualize the sapience of modern man as an extremely fragile crystal vase (=the brain being just barely smart enough) cushioned by a thousand mattresses (=millenia of cultural, societal and civilizational heritage). While the mattresses are there, the vase will secure and nothing could explain people suddenly regressing, it would be incredible. But take away the mattresses, and you're a hair away from disaster. That means, enduring global societal collapse - not hard to imagine, early civilization prospered because of freely available resources (coal and metals literally just lying around in fields). Those resources are now exhausted and require significant expertise and investment to extract, retracing the steps of our ancestors would be much harder now.

The assumption that sapience gives you an edge is not that robust. After all, if it was so powerful how come none of the other animals bothered? Humans did it in a few million years, and yet dinosaurs just never did after 100s of millions? It seems more likely that sapience is almost always not worth it selectively, but humans arose from a rare coincidence: Intelligence happened to deviate into the less fit sapience just as the environment was a perfect storm to kick off and nurture culture. The implication is that when you repeat the "birth of sapience" experiment, most of the time the environment will not be a perfect storm, and highly intelligent species will occasionally see the sapience mutation arise but it will never "take". In fact, these repeated experiments have already been done: Parrots, dolphins, dogs, cats, pigs, squids, octopi...

In sum:

- Sapience will not devolve while culture continues, because culture itself is a strong selective pressure maintaining sapience
- If culture is erased by catastrophe, sapience is left with only a weak positive selective pressure, or even neutral or negative
- The environment of early man might have been uniquely suited to promote sapience and culture, natural environments at other times are not necessarily the same (obvious reasons are resources which are now depleted, but there may be other subtle ones)
- Without culture, sapience can easily devolve
- In absence of culture, if non-sapience is beneficial, it can become fixed over time to reduce the risk of sapience arising in the future

Answer (score 4):

### A metaphysically immense screwup

As you (and various answers) have mentioned, the classic answer is some sort of genetic shift that causes congenital brain damage (or, at least, lack of intelligence), *a la* Planet of the Apes. However, I don't fully buy this. As a former assisted living aide, I've spent much of my life around brain-damaged and/or mentally retarded (in the technical sense of the term) people over the years, and I've never seen either produce anything approaching non-sapience. You're either still sapient but impaired, or it makes you a vegetable; there's no middle ground. Perhaps there is some condition capable of doing this, but if so I've never heard of it. Instead, it seems to me that there must be something else which imparts sapience, some sort of soul, "image of God", or *imago Dei* as the theologians call it.

Now, traditionally, this is something imparted to humans (and, in a sci-fi context, other sapient species) by God/gods/the Flying Spaghetti Monster. Anything with it will be sapient, no matter how stupid; anything without it will be non-sapient, no matter how smart. With this in mind, the answer to your question is obvious: somebody goofed (to use an *immensely* technical term <sup>/s</sup>), and in so doing disrupted, destroyed, dispelled, or otherwise *-ed their species' *imago Dei*.

Perhaps the species experimented just a *little* too much with transhumanist bioengineering, creating *things* so different from the species' base form that they could no longer be considered the same species. Perhaps they committed such heinous crimes against pasta-kind that the Flying Spaghetti Monster revoked their sapience privileges. Who knows; perhaps an eldritch entity from the 42<sup>nd</sup> dimension sneezed in their general direction. The point is, they had souls, and now they don't.

This route can lead in a lot of very interesting directions. For example, in John Scalzi's *Old Man's War* series there's a species called the Obin.

Now, whereas pretty much every other species in the known universe uses something along the lines of "the people" as their name, the Obin are *different*. A literal (and quite accurate) translation of their name is "the lacking". This is because, out of all the species they know of, they are the only ones that aren't sapient. While they think, create technology, work technology, and do other intelligent stuff, they have absolutely no sense of self. They're all just really smart animals.

> It turns out, this is because they are a herd species uplifted by another species, the Consu, which are well on the "sufficiently advanced" side of Clarke's Third Law. More importantly, the Consu think that the *imago Dei* is a curse, so they explicitly chose not to [import soul](https://xkcd.com/413/) when uplifting them.

The Obin *really* don't like being soulless, so they go to great lengths to try to acquire them.

**Edit:** I realize that most people probably wouldn't view this as science-based (although many theologians would beg to differ). I'm just putting this out there as food for thought.

Comment: Your argument isn't very credible either. You might as well claim snakes don't make sense because you've worked with quadruple amputees and never seen them start slithering around. Sudden catastrophic injury is not the same as gradual change over many generations.

Comment: Isn't what you describe with the Obin more like "sapient, but not sentient", rather than "sentient, but not sapient"?  Apparently, "sapient" usually means exactly "think, create technology, work technology, and do other intelligent stuff" (having a complex language being one noticeable part of the "other intelligent stuff") - in other words, the things that humans do that other animals can't, or that humans do orders of magnitude better than other animals.

Comment: @A.B. Good point. I'm always getting the two mixed up. I'll go through and edit my answer to fix this when I have the time.

Comment: I don't want to denigrate your experience with the mentally damaged, but I think people's quick willingness to believe their dog loves them indicates that people, you included, are predisposed to believe the person in front of them has sensible thoughts. In other words, I don't think we can trust your perception, or anyone else's.

Answer (score 4):

They develop artificial intelligence and robotics that completely frees them from any need to support themselves, so sapience becomes unnecessary.

Then genetic drift slowly degrades their intelligence whilst the AI figures our smarter people are less happy and subtly encourages the population away from intellectual pursuits and towards physical prowess, boosting the mating potential of the stupid.

Enough time passes and you have a stupid species permanently maintained by machines it has no hope of comprehending.

Comment: I would also add to this: As society becomes more complex and mature, thinking becomes a liability to all but the elites (as in 1984). What was once advantageous is now selected against, perhaps outside of a small clique of elites who do not interbreed with commoners. In your case, the AI takes the role of the elites.

Answer (score 1):

Environmental conditions that favour brawn over brain in addition to social and cultural regression (e.g children not being fully/correctly taught the language of their parents) could produce an evolutionary pathway that results in reduced intelligence. This answer is purely speculative though, I do not have the knowledge to make confident statements on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Two options that stem from the same idea.

A very infectious bacterial or viral airborne parasite that infects the population which doesn't kill but instead attacks the frontal lobe reducing the average IQ by 70 to 90%.

The second option is again an infectious pathogen but now it infects our reproductive system causing all newborns to have multiple mutations. These mutations are often fatal and or affect the brain reducing the population's IQ.

Achieving non-sapience wouldn't be instantaneous but it would be a byproduct of being affected by either of these conditions for multiple generations (10+). As each generation comes and goes the push to naturally select intelligent beings would be reduced, because in the first there is an external source outright limiting it and in the second there would be a greater push for any being that could actually survive to sexual maturity.

Answer (score 1):

### Sapience Must Become Maladaptive...

Contrary to popular opinion, species don't just lose something because "they don't need it anymore." A species that is fed and happy isn't going to have much evolutionary pressure because, as a fed and happy species, they are successful. To lose sapience, it has to be maladaptive.

### ...But Not Too Maladaptive

It would be pretty easy to just say that there's a virus that hits sapience somehow (attacks that part of the brain?), but let's be honest, anything hitting a species that fast is probably going to wipe out sapience by wiping out the species completely.

So how can you *slowly* kill off sapience in a species?

### Introduce a Predator

Make a predator that hunts your species. It'll eat any member of this species, but it has a special organ that "hears" sapient thought. To this predator, intelligent, self-aware members of your species might as well be screaming. Dumb members are whispering. And those without sapient thought? No "noise" at all. They hunt all members of your species, but the most sapient are easy prey.

This need not be a fast solution. Imagine that these predators might kill 5-10% of each generation.

Comment: Zombie gourmets.

Answer (score 1):

### Welcome to a brave new world!

Huxley had explored this in his book, *Brave New World*. Workers - or Epsilons - were 'cloned' by making sure that the embryos would split, and to do so, the worker embryos were subjected to different nigh-deadly doses of stuff, among them radiation and alcohol, which also had the "desirable" side effect of making the workers dumb and docile. Or let me quote you how *Epsilons* are made, from chapter 1:

> He pointed. On a very slowly moving band a rack-full of test-tubes was entering a large metal box, another, rack-full was emerging. Machinery faintly purred. It took eight minutes for the tubes to go through, he told them. Eight minutes of hard X-rays being about as much as an egg can stand. A few died; of the rest, the least susceptible divided into two; most put out four buds; some eight; all were returned to the incubators, where the buds began to develop; then, after two days, were suddenly chilled, chilled and checked. Two, four, eight, the buds in their turn budded; and having budded were dosed almost to death with alcohol; consequently burgeoned again and having budded–bud out of bud out of bud–were thereafter–further arrest being generally fatal–left to develop in peace. By which time the original egg was in a fair way to becoming anything from eight to ninety-six embryos– a prodigious improvement, you will agree, on nature. Identical twins–but not in piddling twos and threes as in the old viviparous days, when an egg would sometimes accidentally divide; actually by dozens, by scores at a time.
>
> ...
>
> "But in Epsilons," said Mr. Foster very justly, "we don't need human intelligence."

Answer (score 0):

**There is a great story by Larry Niven and Steven Barnes called "the Locusts"**

The locust is a grasshopper that, when facing overpopulation, grows larger and more gregarious and nomadic. They begin traveling in swarms until the overpopulation issue is resolved, then revert to their smaller, more docile state.

*Spoiler alert*
The story suggests that human intelligence shares a similar transient quality. Depopulate the earth by migration to other planets, and they revert to an earlier condition.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers thus far have focused on "intelligence" as being a spectrum or gauge, which is the most common definition. On that scale, we may consider sapience, as H. Beam Piper once wrote, as "a mental boiling point".

Most answers then consider how a species that has achieved sapience would end up reducing their average intelligence, but remaining sapient, staying above that boiling point identifiable by traits like a means of symbolic communication (speech/writing). While those answers are good at answering that reading of your question, there's another way to interpret that question, by considering "intelligence" as "the quantity of mental capability required for sentient thought" and thus a rough synonym of "sapience". Read that way, the question is, **how can a species that has developed a sentient mental state lose that ability to think at a sentient level?**

We have not, in the real world, ever seen this happen, at least not to our knowledge, because to our knowledge we are the only sapient species on this planet, and there have never been more than a handful of distinguishable (but at some level interrelatable) sapient primate species. However, our knowledge of the taxonomy of life on Earth is woefully incomplete; less than 1% of all species to have ever lived on the Earth are extant and thus available for behavioral study, and the fossil record is a notoriously poor source of clues as to a species' mentation (and that's of the species that leave a good fossil record).

So it's absolutely possible that some sauroid species in what's now the Yucatan Peninsula achieved some recognizable form of sapient thought, less than a million years before the nearby Chicxulub Impact wiped them off the map completely, fossil record and all. If the species that ascended to sapience were located further away from the impact site, it might have survived longer and/or their remains might be better preserved, so you'd think we'd have found a couple good fossil skeletal examples. Again, we think we know of less than 1% of all species ever to have lived on this planet, so the unknown space in which such a creature could have existed is fairly large.

Now, that leads us to a pretty good possibility. Sapience tends to require fairly high macronutrient intake for a given body size; that brain needs a lot of blood glucose to function properly. Mass extinction events like the Chicxulub Impact cause a pretty thorough collapse of the food web, and the species with the highest caloric needs often come out on the losing end pretty quickly. **Climate change, asteroid impact, extinction of a key species (honeybees are a good candidate) are all really good ways for *h. sapiens* to find ourselves at an evolutionary dead-end.**

Now, that's kind of cheating, because losing our ability to think because we're dead probably wasn't what you had in mind. However, if you consider our genetic relatives in the primate family as kindred enough, much as we consider modern-day reptiles and birds to be the closest descendants of the dinosaurs (however actually distant), it may well be that some marmoset in the tropical latitudes, on a land mass big enough to stay above the oceans' surface, may end up being the primate family's scion, that some future sapient octopus-derived species will describe as "the closest living relative to these far larger and more intelligent bipedal primates, whose fossil record is endemic on every land mass".

There is an important and closely-related point to make here; The definition of homo sapiens (and, we think, any other life form we identify as sapient) is defined as a species in large part based on that trait. If the human genetic line were, by any chain of events, to "devolve" to a sub-sapient mental state, in whole or part, any remaining sapient observer may well no longer consider those examples to be *homo sapiens* and therefore no longer "human". So there's somewhat of a tautology here; we're human because we're sentient, and if our genetic descendants lose that trait, they'd no longer be human.

---

Anyway, bringing this to an *actual* answer, **it's kind of hard to envision an Earth populated with a genetic descendant of modern humans are no longer sentient, where that didn't happen due to an initial cataclysm that, ironically, makes life easier than before for those who survive the event.** The cataclysm would have to be minimally damaging to the non-human ecosystem (otherwise the food web collapses, which definitely makes life harder and thus forces the remaining humans to have to think more), so asteroid impact is right out, and nuclear war is iffy, but possible if the theories that nuclear winter wouldn't happen are true. Pure climate change is going to make life harder for most as well.

**The only such cataclysm I can think of would be pandemic**, something that makes COVID look like hay fever. *Contagion*'s fictional MEV-1, but even more contagious and deadlier (IIRC, MEV-1 had a mortality rate of 20-30% with an R0 of 4; something closer to 90% mortality with the same contagion rate would about do it), would literally decimate the world population, but for less advanced civilizations, isolated from the developed world and its deadly disease, life would actually get better in the next few hundred years after the virus had burned through the world's population. The severe cut in CO2 production and the dramatic release of pressure on game, fish and forest would, within just a few decades, produce an abundance of living biomass helping to sequester atmospheric CO2, not only reversing climate change but making the caloric needs of your tribe that much easier. If you don't have to think as much about where your next meal comes from, or coordinate as much with fellow humans to get it, you could, conceivably and eventually, arrive at a new steady-state where humans don't *have* to use their impressive brainpower anymore, and over many generations those abilities could atrophy, seeing the species regress to ice-age or earlier intelligence levels.

**The biggest counterexample refuting such a theory is the Sentinelese people.** The inhabitants of North Sentinel Island in the Indian Ocean are fiercely territorial, attacking any outsider who so much as sets foot on the island, such that there is no record of a successful, friendly communication between the Sentinelese and anyone else. There really is no talking to some people. In near-absolute isolation from the rest of the world, the Sentinelese are basically frozen in a neolithic state of development, one of very few known societies to be completely unpolluted by the last, oh, maybe 8,000 years or so of human mental, societal and technological progress. Yet despite all this, **the Sentinelese are definitely sentient** based on everything we have been able to observe at a distance. They have a spoken language, if not a written one, they know of fire and how to produce it, and they make force-altering machines, such as knives and bows and arrows.

While there are some glimmers of these traits among more intelligent animal species, there's no true comparison to be had except to ourselves; these are human beings, however primitive, and they're sapient. Thousands of years of human history passing them by has not changed that, and it's very unlikely thousands more will see much difference. They know what they need to know to survive, at least within their own isolated environment, and whatever folklore they pass down that keeps them so violently wary of outsiders has served them well, as most of the rest of the Andamanese people that populate the Andaman and Nicobar Islands have fared considerably worse against encroachment by non-indigenous cultures (technically part of the Indonesian archipelago, the Andaman and Nicobar Islands are an Indian possession and also close to Myanmar and Thailand).

So at the end of the day, having no more complicated a possession than a bow and arrow doesn't mean you have no inherent capability for sentient thought; quite the contrary, this level of technology is well inside our definition of sapience, and this knocks a big breach in the idea that the human race could ever "lose" our sapience. Merely not progressing isn't regressing.

Comment: Just FYI birds are not the closest separate group to the dinosaurs, they ARE dinosaurs, the direct descendants of one group of dinosaurs in particular. Birds are dinosaurs in the same way you are a great ape.

Answer (score 0):

### you rule our forced genetic tampering what about, accidental genetic tampering?

1. Colony worlds will be especially prone to this, since the starting population is small. They decide to tamper with the colonist to make them better adapted to the local planet but oops it turns out the tampering has no adverse effect on adults but made all your kids stupid.
2. Then you have voluntary tampering, designer babies people making babies who are more attractive, no few are likely to intentionally make their kids dumber but what if it is not a direct effect, the effect skips the first generation or Gene X is determined to be responsible for brain cancer type Y so people get it "fixed" in their kids, but it also turns out to be necessary for normal brain development.  Or more realistically gene babies type A breed with gene babies type B and the two alteration don't play well together in the brain. You would need to combine this with something that kills off a lot of the population otherwise it will get fixed, maybe a plague that gene babies are immune too.
3. Another option is war, country X creates a gene altering virus to make all (choose your minority here) stupid or their kids stupid and low a behold people willing to commit atrocities don't have the best minds or safety protocols and it affects everyone. Or they make it to kill and instead it just shuts down the tiny number of genes needed to make us smarter than chimps.

Answer (score -1):

### Peak of Evolutionary Intelligence has surpassed and reboot via Devolution

Intelligence is an evolutionary trait that may take millions of years and several thousands of generations to develop. Your species is sapient and intelligent which makes me think that they are very likely to hit the peak of the *collective species intelligence* very soon. It's almost impossible that the species would continue to evolve eternally. If they are careful enough not to bring up their own doom, Nature may be likely to bring them the catastrophe.

Note that the biggest power a sapient and intelligent species has is its own sentience which if lost would render the species to perish. Non-sapient species might not be at that great disadvantage because as we develop more and more sentience, our ability to survive become more dependent on our sentience. For example, humans have created artificial means of curing diseases and prolonging life. If all our technology were to vanish suddenly, we wouldn't quickly return to way we used to survive some hundred years ago or so. There will be required something much more tremendous for that. So once the peak of their *evolutionary intelligence* is surpassed, they would start to decline their intelligence and probably sentience too. This would not happen overnight. It might take several thousand years. But it would be inevitable since it is largely natural.

If you want to take it further, you may say that after a continual decline of intelligence, there would be a reboot and a new cycle could start such that another sapient and intelligent species would arise, would reach a peak and again declining. This all could be *natural* and *inevitable* regardless of their efforts to undo it. The **peaks** of the successive cycles could be more or less drastic.

It is kind of similar to the fall of the Galactic Empire in *Foundation* trilogy by Isaac Asimov in which the Empire falls apart no matter how much the Emperor resists.

Comment: collective species intelligence is not something that undergoes evolutionary selection, group selection is always overridden by gene line selection.